Transfer data from a Xbox One game to same game Xbox Series S/X version
I have a Xbox Series S and a game with its version for Xbox One and its version optimized for Xbox Series S/X.
I would like to transfer the data of this game in its version Series S/X and pass it to the same game (in the same console) but in its version Xbox One.
In this case the game is WWE 2K23, but it is applicable to any other game with both versions.

I assume by data you mean save data?

This is possible using Xbox cloud game saves, as described in Moving from Xbox One to Xbox Series X|S.

Xbox Series X|S is backward compatible across all generations of Xbox, and the list of back compat games is expanding. To continue playing a game on Xbox Series X|S that you started on Xbox One, make sure it’s saved it to the cloud. When you play the game again on Xbox Series X|S, you’ll pick up where you left off. You can find all the games and apps you own that are available to download to your Xbox Series X|S console in My games & apps.

The caveat is not all games appear to be supported by the way this is worded.  Your particular game WWE 2K23 does appear to support Xbox Cloud Saves according to its store page, so, make sure the save data is present in the Xbox Cloud, and it should be pretty much plug-n-play when you try to play it on your Xbox Series S console.
